# Чем отличаются способы присвоить строку?

Tags: java, строки

**Хотел спросить чем отличается:** 
`String name = "Mike";`
**от**
`String name = new String()`;

 **или же**

```
String name = new String("Вася");
```

**В 1 случае** мы создаём переменную и присваиваем ей значение **`Mike`**,
**Во втором случае** создаём объект и присваиваем туда значение **`Вася`**, это 2 объявления одинаковых и мы можем это либо так либо так делать?

Comment: Первый вариант - называется литералом и он будет попадать в строковый пул, а второй вариант будет храниться в хипе.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext

Comment: А StringBuilder при чём?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev извиняюсь, исправил

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае вы объявляете ссылочную переменную строкового типа и присваиваете ей ссылку на литерал в пуле констант. Во втором случае вы вызываете конструктор `String`, передавая ему ссылку на литерал, конструктор создаёт объект, инициализирует в нём поле, содержащее массив символов, и копирует в этот массив символы из литерала. Возвращённая конструктором ссылка присваивается переменной `name`. В обоих случаях в переменной `name` оказывается ссылка на строку, но во втором виртуальной машине придётся выполнить больше операций и использовать больше памяти, так как один экземпляр строки будет хранится в пуле констант, а второй в куче.

Comment: Это может быть не совсем так. HotSpot интернирует строки, поэтому ссылка на литерал и ссылка на объект будут указывать на один элемент пула строк.